# remove part of string record in mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

this is my string record on tables in mysql

"ftp://myftp.co/ftp/Media_Gallery//Cartoon/Serries/Shaun_The_Sheep/Shaun_The_Sheep_E015.mkv"

now i want remove "//" at the center of my string after "Media_Gallery"

but when i use replace queries // this query remove // at the first of URL and its wrong

my string after run query would be this scheme:
    "ftp://ftp.um.ac.ir/ftp/Media_Gallery/Cartoon/Serries/Shaun_The_Sheep/Shaun_The_Sheep_E015.mkv"

Comment: Please post everything here. I can't get access to the link you provided.

Comment: this is a string not VALID LINK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE Mytable SET name = REPLACE(`name`, 'y//', 'y/');